Unable to elevate permissions in Python module entry points
I'm trying to design a Python module with entry points that would request an elevation in permission when called on Windows.
setup.py
setup(
    name='SomePackage',
    ...
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    python_requires='>=3.6, <4',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'thecommand=some_package.entrypoints.entrypoints:execute_command',
        ],
    },
    ...
)

src/some_package.entrypoints.entrypoints.py
def elevate_permission():
    if not ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
        sys.exit(0)


def execute_command():
    
    # ... Some argparser stuff

    elevate_permission() # Request admin permissions here to execute the following args.func(args).
    time.sleep(10)
        
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if hasattr(args, 'func'):
        try:
            args.func(args)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nKeybord Interupt!")
    else:
        parser.print_help()

In this setup, the program is designed to request administrative privileges for Python3 by rerunning the user's initial command in a new shell with elevated permissions. Although the elevation request works (triggering a prompt asking if Python3 can make changes to the device), the program fails to proceed correctly. It doesn't open a new shell window or execute the command as expected.
The time.sleep(10) line was specifically added to prevent the administrative shell from closing immediately after launching; however, this line does not execute in the new shell.
I also attempted to simplify the process by using the elevate package, replacing the custom elevation function with:
from elevate import elevate; elevate()

However, the outcome remains unchanged—the program halts after the user grants admin permissions in the pop-up window, and no administrative shell is created.
